# Is there a way to manually import bookmarks to xmarks?

Tags: sync, bookmarks, xmarks

I've had no luck finding a suitable xmarks alternative that works with proxy servers (see [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/342552/xmarks-alternative-for-cross-browser-bookmarks-sync-with-a-proxy-server)) so I'm willing to settle for manually updating bookmarks from my work computer. My proposed workflow would be something like this:

- At home, auto-update in xmarks as usual.
- At work, where xmarks can no longer upload bookmarks: at the end of each day, save my current bookmarks to a file of some kind, go to xmarks.com, and manually upload that file.

However I don't see any option like this.

So my question is:  is there any way to get my current bookmarks onto the xmarks server when the normal synchronize process won't work because I have to go through a proxy?

Comment: @sblair [Should non-substantial edits be approved or rejected?](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2896/should-non-substantial-edits-be-approved-or-rejected/2898#2898). But thanks for improving it.

Comment: @slhck Good point. I nearly rejected it until I spotted some further improvements - I've just realised that "Improve" still rewards the original editor.